# Decimal.js sin() function returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, decimal.js

I have a javascript program that looks like this:

```
function dosine(){
    var num = new Decimal(document.getElementById('num').value);
    if(document.getElementById('degrad').value == "degrees"){
        num = (num*Math.PI)/180;
        console.log(num);
    }
    num = Decimal.sin(num);
    console.log(num.toString());
    numinverse = Decimal.asin(num);
    if(document.getElementById('degrad').value == "degrees"){
        num = num * (180/Math.PI);
        numinverse = numinverse * (180/Math.PI);
    }
    document.getElementById('resultsine').innerHTML = "Sine: " + num.toString();
    document.getElementById('resultinverse').innerHTML = "Inverse Sine: " + numinverse.toString();
}
```

In my program, I am now using Degrees.sin and Degrees.asin because of floating-point weirdness with the Math library, but when I get the sin output for 64 I get 51.49710550442818, but on my physical calculator I get <s>0.920026038197</s> 0.8987940463. Am I using this library wrong, or is my code just not good? I am pretty new to javascript so advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The range of the sin function is between -1 and 1, so getting an output outside of that range signals a problem.  sin of 64 degrees is also ~0.8988.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to clarify, I converted the input to radians before putting it through the sin function, so it should be between those two values

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `Decimal`. You convert `num` to radians, then you take a sine of it. Finally you convert the result of the sine (which should be a proportion from 0 to 1, not an angle!) from radians to degrees, which makes no sense - it's like converting weight from feet into metres.

This could be avoided by using better naming conventions, using variable names that make sure you know what the variable contains. `num` is not very semantic - all it tells you is that it has a number in it. Consider `angle_in_degrees`, `angle_in_radians` and `sine`. Then it would be immediately obvious that this is not what you want:

```
angle_in_radians = Decimal.sin(angle_in_radians)  // result is a sine ratio, not an angle!
angle_in_degrees = angle_in_radians * (180 / Math.PI); // good operation on bad data
```

---

Another big point is that your code does not stay in `Decimal`. JavaScript cannot override the default operations, so you have to use `Decimal` methods to calculate, not `+`, `*` and `/`. Note this:

```
Decimal(1) + 3 // incorrect
// => "13"
Decimal(1).add(3).toNumber() // correct
// => 4
```

Finally, unless you are dealing with financial systems, the floating point error is usually negligible; moreover, the result of sine function is irrational, so it can't be represented in `Decimal` any more correctly than in floating point anyway. Unless you have a use case that makes `Decimal.js` necessary, just use the normal numbers.